# Как посмотреть содержимое корня архива без вывода всех файлов?

Tags: linux, tar

В архиве несколько миллионов файлов в папках, нужно посмотреть, какие в корне каталоги.

Comment: Сильно зависит от типа архива. Что у вас?

Comment: У меня tgz   У меня tgz

Comment: Подозреваю, что ничего лучше tar | grep не будет

Comment: Хоть раз бы, приняли ответы.

Answer (score 3):

в комментариях упомянут формат архива [tar](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar).

уже из самого названия — tape archive (ленточный архив) — становится понятно, что информация о файле хранится в архиве **рядом** с содержимым файла, т.е. не сосредоточена в одном месте архива, а «размазана» по всему его содержимому. и сделано это намеренно, чтобы для добавления нового файла в архив можно было просто дописать необходимую информацию в конец архива, не перезаписывая всё его содержимое.

поэтому, чтобы собрать информацию об архивированных файлах (например, пути к файлам в иерархии каталогов), понадобится просмотр **всего** архива (а если он сжат каким-нибудь компрессором (*gzip, zip, bzip, xz* и т.д. и т.п.) — то ещё и его декомпрессия).

---

но, конечно, можно сгруппировать уже полученную информацию — для удобства просмотра.

например, чтобы извлечь только первый компонент из путей к файлам и убрать дубликаты, можно воспользоваться такой, например, командой:

```
$ tar -tf архив | grep -Eo '^/?[^/]+' | sort -u
```

здесь:

- программа *tar* выводит в *stdout* список содержимого архива
- программа *grep* «вырезает» первый компонент пути
- программа *sort* сортирует и, благодаря опции `-u`, удаляет дубликаты